# Update textInput after clicking on it

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I just want to remove text value (put blank text) of a textInput after clicking on it. I tryed "updateTextInput" or "onclick" from shinyjs without success, any idea ?

```
if (interactive()) {
ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel("test textInput clicking"),

sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
        textInput("sequenceTextInput", label = "", value = "Enter sequence 
                   here...")
    ),
    mainPanel(
    )  
))

server = function(input, output) {
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this to work with shinyjs as follows:

```
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("test textInput clicking"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      useShinyjs(),
          textInput("sequenceTextInput", label = "", value = "Enter sequence here...")

    ),
    mainPanel(
    )  
  ))

server = function(input, output,session) {
  onclick("sequenceTextInput",updateTextInput(session,"sequenceTextInput",value=""))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Hope this helps!